# if any element from arr1 is equal to id of obj of arr match.. leave this and put rest of the arr1 element in emptyArr

Tags: javascript

Code:

```
var arr1 = [3,4,5];
var arr = [{id:1, name:"arup"}, {id:2, name:"dinesh"}, {id:3, name:"raju"}];
var emptyArr = [];


expected result => emptyArr = [4,5]
```

If any element from `arr1` is equal to `id` of obj of arr match.. leave this put rest of the element from arr1 into `emptyArr`.
(using a filter, don't want to use 'delete' any element from arr1)

Comment: You want to find all the values in `arr1` that don't have a corresponding object in `arr`?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the first array and use `some` function to check if the element is present as `id` in second array. `some` will return `true` or `false`>If not present it return false.

```js
var arr1 = [3,4,5];
var emptyArr = [];
var arr = [{id:1, name:"arup"}, {id:2, name:"dinesh"}, {id:3, name:"raju"}];
arr1.forEach(function(item){
 let z = arr.some(function(elm){
   return elm.id === item
 })
if(!z){
  emptyArr.push(item)
}

})
console.log(emptyArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest way, using `some` in the filter to check if at least one object is satisfying the condition and return false if so. I hope this is not too much confusing to you.

```
var emptyArr = arr1.filter(e=>!arr.some(obj=>obj.id === e))
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a new array with just id's and then used includes to check if arr1 elements are present in arr

```js
var arr1 = [3,4,5];
var arr = [{id:1, name:"arup"}, {id:2, name:"dinesh"}, {id:3, name:"raju"}];
let z = arr.map(o => o.id)
var emptyArr = [];
arr1.forEach(i => { if(!z.includes(i)){emptyArr.push(i)}})
console.log(emptyArr)
```

Comment: `arr.map(o => o.id)` is an overhead